# Why Is Tkinter Outputting Before I Push The Button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create a simple "Store App" that will add the item name and cost to a dictionary and then output it, but whenever I go to run my program it adds both items to cart before I have even clicked the buttons. I am not sure if it is a python problem, or something to do with how Tkinter works. Any help would be appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Number Sorter")
root.geometry('600x600')

cart_list = {"Item_Name": [], "Price": []}

def purchaseClick(Name, Price):
    cart_list["Item_Name"].append(Name)
    cart_list["Price"].append(Price)

title1 = Label(root, text="The Solar War by A.G Riddle")
item1_name = "The Solar War"
item1_price = 11.99
title1.pack()

purchasebtn = Button(root, text="Purchase", command = purchaseClick(item1_name, item1_price))
purchasebtn.pack()

title2 = Label(root, text="Elon Musk By Ashlee Vance")
item2_name = "Elon Musk"
item2_price = 9.99
title2.pack()

purchasebtn = Button(root, text="Purchase", command = purchaseClick(item2_name, item2_price))
purchasebtn.pack()

cart_list_show = Label(root, text=cart_list)
cart_list_show.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because `Button.command` takes a function as an argument, not the output. So, you have to pass just `purchaseClick` and not `purchaseClick(item1, price1)`.

But in your case you need to pass in arguments too, so change the line from

```
purchasebtn = Button(root, text="Purchase", command = purchaseClick(item1_name, item1_price))
```

to this,

```
purchasebtn = Button(root, text="Purchase", command = lambda : purchaseClick(item1_name, item1_price))
```

I am fairly sure this is gonna do the work for you.